# Twitter integration to iOS without using third party library and social.framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to create a library for Twitter to integrate into iOS apps. For that I am looking for a good tutorial or documentation to start with. Twitter does not seem to have any examples.

Please note that I want to create my own library and hence, I don't want to use any third party library already available. I also don't want to use social.framework included in iOS SDK as I want to tweet in background without displaying any view such as Tweet Sheet.

Looking for a good tutorial for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is not a complete answer, a few suggestions only. I don't think you can find a tutorial to create a library for twitter. Twitter also not giving any SDK only they documented the rest apis and their use [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). They are using OAuth1.0 for user authentication. So you need to authenticate the user to access these api.

For authentication:

- Authentication  through web view
- [Reverse auth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth)

Its better to check an open source implementation and make yourself. [FHSTwitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine) is one of them that you can refer. It is lacking reverse auth, you may want to add.

Comment: Link is broken: https://ton.twimg.com/dtc/33414a20-ac3f-4f46-b0f8-63aef9b2dbb8/docs/api/1.1